# Map-base-odom relationship for external localizator

Tags: ros, navigation, localization, tf-tree

I am using an external positioning device, and the device sends the vehicle's location data to ROS via UDP while also performing TF transformations. I provide the map frame as the "parent frame" and the base_link frame as the "child frame" parameters for this TF transformation. As a result, I can track the vehicle's location on the map and perform simple navigation applications.

To improve the vehicle's driving, I plan to provide the vehicle's odometry to the navigation package, but I'm currently stuck on how to establish the TF connections at this point.

The positioning software is already providing the transformation between the map and base_link. The odometry package I've developed also provides the transformation between odom and base_link. I've tried creating a connection like map -> odom -> base_link -> laser_link, but this approach seems impractical (the TF tree is shown below). I'm unsure about how to merge these elements, and I'd appreciate your assistance.

[image: TF Tree]